# GCP - Service Account key - JSON download fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I created a new service account and I was trying to generate a key for it. I selected "Create Key", chose "JSON", and then this happens:

[Download image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnGJ.png)

The download just doesn't happen (0kb size and host is null), I've tried on different browsers, different computers and I don't know what to do, the problem doesn't seem to be on my side...

What can I do about this?

Comment: I just tried it in my project and it worked fine.  Can you try from a different computer?  My gut is thinking some security package on your local PC.  What roles does your current user have?  Are you logged  into the GCP console with a constrained identity?

Comment: I have tried from 3 different computers (and all on different locations), one of the computers was actually from a project teammate. My current user is the owner of the project

Comment: Also, I've tried to create a project from scratch on gcp. Went to IAM & Admin -> Created a new service account -> created a key -> JSON -> The problem still persists.

Comment: Let's try another test ... from a Cloud Shell, run: `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create myfile.json --iam-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`

Comment: Use Google Chrome. Then turn on the debugger by pressing F-12. Repeat your steps and then post the errors you see in the debugger. Note: Your symptoms could also be antivirus software blocking the download.

Comment: You may try Private Browsing mode (Incognito mode in Chrome). Sometimes such misbehavior could be caused by browser add-ons or Ad blockers.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem.

In order to access the Service Account Key file you need to ensure that you can use your API Key (under your Project Credentials), which may be restricted.

My API Key was restricted to my IP address and to the specific API I wanted to use.
After removing the API restriction only then did the download work (see below).

Hope this helps.

[UI showing API restrictions removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPe25.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem but got solved by changing my browser.
Since I was working with the brave browser and was unable to download this file.
After that, I changed my browser to chrome. The problem was solved.

SOMETIME BROWSER CAN HAVE SOME ISSUE.